# I cannot find SpringToolSuite4.ini file in the new version of SpringToolSuite4(4.1.2). It seems be changed to manage .ini.file. Where can I find it?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I need to change some configuration information to use SpringToolSuite4. But when I downloaded SpringToolSuite4 4.1.2 and unziped, there isn't SpringToolSuite4.ini file. So I created one, but SpringToolSuite4 didn't reference to SpringToolSuite4.ini file when starting.

Comment: I can see a `SpringToolSuite4.ini` file when I unzip the Spring Tool Suite 4.1.2 download for Windows, it is next to the SpringToolSuite4.exe file. Maybe a proxy server in between that checks ZIP files and removes stuff from it?

Comment: Thank you for Martin Lippert's reply. After re-downloaded, I can find it. But I don't know why I couldn't find it a few days ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem with these steps:

1. Open the commad terminal;
2. go to the location where you put the jar file;
3. Run "java -jar [****.jar]";

PS: Make sure you have java runtime installed in you machine and you have the correct environment settings.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Kind of funny that they would choose to bundle STS into a .jar file that might misfire like that instead of a regular .zip that everyone can extract without any issues 100% of the time. Your fix worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is an admin rights problem:

I have downloaded the self extracting .jar file:
spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.1.RELEASE-e4.17.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar

I saved it in c:\Program Files (needs admin rights).

Double-clicked it (not as admin) -> Same error (cannot find the SpringToolSuite4.ini file).

I have started TotalCommander (you may use a differnt explorer) with admin rights -> Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Open *jar* with winrar. Open the "contents.zip". Move to "sts-4.8.0.RELEASE" folder in documents. After, we run the program.

*jar*:spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.0.RELEASE-e4.17.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting

[image]

You can solve the problem like this.

Comment: When I downloaded it for the second time. I also got this error(SpringToolSuite4.ini). Downloading it again didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When I downloaded it for the second time. I also got this error(SpringToolSuite4.ini). That's how I passed. instead of downloading it again. Downloading it again didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the sts icon inside the extracted sts-bundle package and select show content.